# MySQL - Returning Multiple Rows of the Same Order ID

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to retrieve data with the following query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
o.id_order AS ID,
c.name AS ID_Carrier,
sl.name AS Store_Location,
o.date_add AS Order_date,
CASE WHEN h.id_order_state='2' THEN h.date_add END AS PAYMENT_VALIDATED,
CASE WHEN h.id_order_state='3' THEN h.date_add END AS IN_PROGRESS,
CASE WHEN h.id_order_state='160' THEN h.date_add END AS AWAITING,
CASE WHEN h.id_order_state='161' THEN h.date_add END AS SHIPPED,
CASE WHEN h.id_order_state='162' THEN h.date_add END AS READY_TO_COLLECT,
CASE WHEN h.id_order_state='84' THEN h.date_add END AS COLLECTED
FROM de_order_history h
LEFT JOIN de_orders o ON (o.id_order=h.id_order)
LEFT JOIN de_carrier c ON (o.id_carrier=c.id_carrier)
LEFT JOIN de_clickandcollect fs ON (o.id_order = fs.id_order)
LEFT JOIN de_store s ON (fs.id_store=s.id_store)
LEFT JOIN de_store_lang sl ON (sl.id_store=s.id_store)
WHERE sl.name = "XXX"
AND o.date_add >=  "2019-02-12 00:00:01"
AND o.date_add <=  "2019-02-12 23:59:59"
```

The query above is returning valid data but I would like to turn it into one row for a specific order. At the moment, I believe due to the multiple records created in de_order_history of the same id_order,

I am receiving below :

[image: SQL ERROR]

Since these records are from the same id_order, I want to make it into one row.

I have tried the following :

```
MAX(CASE WHEN h.id_order_state='2' THEN h.date_add END) AS 01_PAYMENT_VALIDATED
```

Unfortunately, Prestashop 1.7 is returning an error due to the "END". I am baffled on the issue too.

Is there any way I can achieve my goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `group by` in your requete ?

Regards

Comment: Hello ethercreation, I have tried GROUP BY o.id_order initially by it's returning the first h.id_order_state. (CASE WHEN h.id_order_state='2' THEN h.date_add END AS PAYMENT_VALIDATED).